# 7zip CLI whitelist files to add by extension

Tags: file-extension, 7zip, whitelist

If I'm running the 7z a -tzip myDestFile.zip some/dir command and I want to add to it a file extension whitelist, such that if I put *.txt *.xls *.doc, it will only add files with those extensions to the archive, how would I do that?  The documentation does well at whitelisting by a single extension, but what about multiple?  Am I just going to have to run the command several times in my script?

I've tried the following:

```
7za a -tzip test.zip ./subdir *.txt *.xlsx # throws error
7za a -tzip test.zip ./subdir -i!./*.txt -i!./*.xlsx # also results in error
7za a -tzip test.zip ./subdir -i!*.txt -i!*.xlsx # also results in error
```

Comment: Nevermind, this works if I include the full subdir with each extension.  Example to be included in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question shouldn't remain open.  The answer that worked for me is below:

`7za a -tzip test.zip ./*.txt ./*.xlsx`