# Use of 7zip "exclude wildcards" in batch file

Tags: batch-file, 7zip, file-extension

I have a batch file for project backup, that i want to modify to exclude unnecessary files.

My current file uses simple 7z command to pack whole folder into one archive:

```
!7zipPath! a -t7z "archive_name" "path_to_add".
```

From what i found in other people questions, to exclude given files, i can use flag, for example **-x!*.txt***, or **-xr!.txt** if path consist subfolders.

```
!7zipPath! a -t7z "archive_name" "path_to_add" -xr!*.jt
```

This should exclude all files with .jt extension (software specific extension), but -x!*.jt returns "incorrect wildcard typemaker *.jt
So from what i understand 7zip does not know this extension so i can not use it (is that correct thinking?)

So instead i tried to use include only. Answers from other question says that it should be simply added like this:

```
!7zipPath! a -t7z "archive_name" "path_to_add" ./*.xml
```

In my understanding this should create archive that includes only .xml files while keeping structure, but it just ignores that wildcard and put all the files from the path. It does not return any kind of error.

How can i use 7zip command options in batch file 7z command to get expected results?

PS; Will it work with extension on a folder? So that it would include whole folder.cojt for example?

EDIT: Full code

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
rem Get the time from WMI - at least that's a format we can work with
set X=
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined X set X=%%x
rem dissect into parts
set DATE.YEAR=%X:~0,4%
set DATE.MONTH=%X:~4,2%
set DATE.DAY=%X:~6,2%

echo Today is: %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY%

if not exist %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY% (
echo Making Backup

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('where /r "C:\Program Files\7-Zip" /f 7z.exe') do Set zipPath=%%A
IF NOT DEFINED zipPath (
echo Extending search range for 7zip...
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('where /r C:\ /f 7z.exe') do Set zipPath=%%A
)
IF NOT DEFINED zipPath (
echo Extending search range for 7zip...
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('where /r D:\ /f 7z.exe') do Set zipPath=%%A
)
IF NOT DEFINED zipPath (
echo 7zip not found on this PC
echo You can close this window now
cmd /k
)

md %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY%
cd %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY%

!zipPath! a -t7z "%DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY%_TuneCells" "M:\01\TuneCells\" 
)
if exist %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY% (
echo Backup already created %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY%
)

PAUSE
```

As mentioned in one of commends, the search for 7z is there so that multiple people can easily use the code regardless of their installation path preferences (which are surprisingly wide)

Comment: It looks as if you're using delayed expansion, without telling us why or showing us the command line in the context of your batch file. When using delayed expansion, your **`!`** in `-xr!*.jt` is bound to be problematic.

Comment: Your second command work on my PC without any problem. To include only a certain type, use this command: `!7zipPath! a -t7z "compressname" -ir!*.xml`

Comment: I made the base file a while ago and actually had to read what was it doing again.  I'm using them because i search for 7zip exe (the !7zipPath! var) on user PC so that multiple people can run this file.
I understand why -x! cause problems, but why is the last code not working, giving me all the files instead of just xmls?

Comment: Why are you using `./*.xml`? Windows uses a backslash as a path separator, and a relative path `.\ ` seems completely pointless. Please provide more of your batch file in order that an in context solution can be offered.

Comment: I tried to "cheat" the ! into the commands by saving variable params="-xr!*.jt" and then using ```!7zipPath! a -t7z "archive_name" "path_to_add" !params!``` It does not return error, but it still include .jt files :/

Comment: @Compo
I used ```./*.xml``` because that was solution here
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636349/7zip-cli-whitelist-files-to-add-by-extension)

Comment: @Legith, that linked answer does not carry a [tag:windows] tag, a [tag:batch-file] tag, or a [tag:cmd] tag, so it should not be seen a relevant for your purpose.

Comment: Also, as I've already mentioned it, you appear to be using delayed expansion, which causes a problem with **`!`** characters, but at no point have you used any code which requires expansion to be delayed. So change the line, `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to `SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion`, and use `%zipPath%` in your subsequent code instead of `!zipPath!`.

Comment: I'm sorry for delayed answer. We had a little dissaster at work and i forgot about the topic. If i apply your solution %zipPath% appears as empty variable for the batch file and i can not execute any 7zip commands. If i remember correctly, i've been using delayed expression to make sure that variable is set during program execution rather than upfront on the beginning.